# I'm trying to prototype inherit calendar.event but I get errors

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

```
class MeetingRoom(models.Model):
    _name = 'meeting.room'
    _inherit = "calendar.event"

    categ_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'calendar.event.type', 'meeting_room_categ_rel', 'meeting_room_id', 'type_id', 'Tags')
    room_id = fields.Many2one('meeting.room.room')
```

If I don't include categ_ids, I get this error: "TypeError: Many2many fields meeting.room.categ_ids and calendar.event.categ_ids use the same table and columns"

When I include categ_ids, I get this error:

psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "meeting_room_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Many2many `relation` name

***Example:***

```py
categ_ids = fields.Many2many(relation='meeting_room_category_rel')
partner_ids = fields.Many2many(relation='meeting_room_res_partner_rel')
alarm_ids = fields.Many2many(relation='calendar_alarm_meeting_room_rel')
```

You need also to update the functions that use `calendar.event` records like [_find_attendee_batch](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/calendar/models/calendar_event.py#L1164)  which is used in a compute method

There are references to `calendar.event` in the inverse fields of `attendee_ids` and `activity_ids`, so you need to override those  fields too and update the code with the new field names

***Example:***

```py
class MeetingRoom(models.Model):
    _name = 'meeting.room'
    _inherit = "calendar.event"

    def _find_attendee_batch(self):
        """ Return the first attendee where the user connected has been invited
            or the attendee selected in the filter that is the owner
            from all the meeting_ids in parameters.
        """
        result = defaultdict(lambda: self.env['calendar.attendee'])
        self_attendees = self.attendee_ids.filtered(lambda a: a.partner_id == self.env.user.partner_id)
        for attendee in self_attendees:
            result[attendee.meeting_event_id.id] = attendee
        remaining_events = self - self_attendees.meeting_event_id

        events_checked_partners = self.env['calendar.filters'].search([
            ('user_id', '=', self.env.user.id),
            ('partner_id', 'in', remaining_events.attendee_ids.partner_id.ids),
            ('partner_checked', '=', True)
        ]).partner_id
        filter_events = self.env['meeting.room']
        for event in remaining_events:
            event_partners = event.attendee_ids.partner_id
            event_checked_partners = events_checked_partners & event_partners
            if event.partner_id in event_checked_partners and event.partner_id in event_partners:
                filter_events |= event
                result[event.id] = event.attendee_ids.filtered(lambda attendee: attendee.partner_id == event.partner_id)[:1]
        remaining_events -= filter_events

        for event in remaining_events:
            event_checked_partners = events_checked_partners & event_partners
            attendee = event.attendee_ids.filtered(
                lambda a: a.partner_id in event_checked_partners and a.state != "needsAction")
            result[event.id] = attendee[:1]
        return result
    activity_ids = fields.One2many(inverse_name='meeting_room_id')
    attendee_ids = fields.One2many(inverse_name='meeting_event_id')


class MailActivity(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mail.activity'

    meeting_room_id = fields.Many2one('meeting.room')


class CalendarAttendee(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'calendar.attendee'

    meeting_event_id = fields.Many2one('meeting.room')
```

`calendar.event` model name is hard coded in `write`, `default_get`, `_create_videocall_channel`, `_create_videocall_channel_id`, `action_open_composer`, `_setup_alarms` and `_break_recurrence` functions

You could have issues with functions calling `super`.

If you have no reason to create a separate model, just extend the `calendar.event` model,  create separate views and menus for the meeting room